# Javascript Weird Loop Behaviour

Tags: javascript, loops

This is a very strange javascript behaviour, anyone can explain that ?

```
for(var i=0; i < 0.2 ; i += 0.05)
   {
    console.log(i);
   }
```

Return in console :

```
0 
0.05 
0.1 
0.15000000000000002
```

0.15000000000000002  ?

What is this ?

Comment: It's IEEE's floating number's issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Recommend to see https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/ or https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about floating point numbers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Also, there are some nice answers here: [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)